# Find total resistance using LTspice

Tags: voltage, resistors, resistance, ltspice

How can I calculate the total resistance of resistors combination between points a and b ?

I have already designed the circuit and added a 1 A current source between a and b.
For dependent current source I used component g (voltage dependent current source).

[image: Electrical circuit]

Solving node equations I was able to find Rab using Ohm's law .
According to my calculations V1 = 1.8282... V and V2 = 5.4545... V .

Rab = Vab / 1 = Vx

[image: III_LTspice]

My question is how can I find voltage Vab = Vx ?

Comment: For your circuit with a 1A current source, the Vx voltage is equal to 5.4545..V

Comment: Your inputs for the VCCS are reversed.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you very much, that solved the problem .

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the problem pointed out in comments where you didn't correctly capture the schematic,

> My question is how can I find voltage Vab = Vx ?

Your `b` node is connected to ground so its voltage (as reported by SPICE) is always 0.

Therefore what you call \$V_{ab}\$ is what SPICE calls `V(a)`, which is reported in the screen image you provided.